# Removing trademark from the string PHP - my method

Tags: php, string, symbols

I know that this topic was solved here, but I made my method and I don't understand why it isn't functional.

I have a following code:

```
$string1 = "sandisk-mobilemate™-duo";

$str_length1 = strlen($string1);

for($i = 0; $i < $str_length1; $i++){
    echo $string1[$i]." = ".ord($string1[$i])."<BR />";
    if((ord($string1[$i]) == 226) || (ord($string1[$i]) == 132) || (ord($string1[$i]) == 162)){
        $string1[$i] == '';
    }
}

echo $string1.'<BR />';
```

Now some comments. The loop controls the string character by character. In the first step it shows the output of each character in ASCII. In this step I realized that TM mark is consisting of three chars (226, 132, 162 in ASCII). So the second step should replace this chars by an empty character (''). But I don't understand why this doesn't happen.

Thank you for your correction and explanation.

Comment: your method does not work because of $string1[$i] == ''; it should be $string1[$i] = '';.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to mess around with ascii values, just remove the symbol

```
$string1 = 'sandisk-mobilemate™-duo';
$string2 = str_replace('™', '', $string1);
echo $string2;

// sandisk-mobilemate-duo
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot, because I tried also your method and I wasn't succesfull so I decided to make it this way.